# CIHeightFieldFromMask filter for ios

Tags: ios, image-processing, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

How can I create same efftect as in MacOs filter CIHeightFieldFromMask?
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Art/CIHeightFieldFromMask.jpg

I can't find algorithm for this. In description says that it is loft-shaped height field, but I don't know how to do it.